# Getting null in console when accessing using key

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am new in Angular. I am consoling 2 things. In which in first console i am getting data properly. But in next console, i am getting data as null.

```
onOriginalBlocksSelect(item: any, index) {
    console.log("item",item)
    console.log("item1",item.value) 
}
```

> this is my first console data

[image]

> this is my second console data
>
> [image]

as in first image: in value key i am getting data in `blocksOriginal` but in second image i am getting `blocksOriginal` as null. Why?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access form control values, can you please create a stackblitz that will help to debug your issue.

Comment: @KamranKhatti i dont know how to create it. But can you please help me why i am getting null value

Comment: Go to https://stackblitz.com/ and create an angular app example of what you have, move your code there and set up a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Since your item is a type of FormGroup, you can get values simply like this:

```
onOriginalBlocksSelect(item: FormGroup, index) {
    console.log("item",item)
    const values = this.item.getRawValue(); 
    console.log("values:" , values); // it should show what you are looking for 
}
```

Comment: still getting null

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz repo?